# Controlling the automatic name of a website project in a visual studio

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, web, project

Is there a way to specifically name a website project "Website" in a visual studio 2012 solution?

For example:

1. Create a blank solution at `c:\temp\Solution`
2. Right-click in solution explorer, select Add New Website at `c:\temp\Solution\Website`

---

Problem:

In solution explorer, the website will be named something like `Website(1)` or `Website(2)`, etc. instead of just `Website`?

Is this a flaw in visual studio or user error?

Comment: do you already have a site at `c:\temp\Solution\Website`?

Comment: @Eonasdan - No, the solution folder is empty (aside from the .sln, .suo solution files.)

Give those 2 steps a try and you'll see what I'm describing. Start out fresh without any c:\temp\Solution folder. It's not a major problem of course, but strange nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

it mostly happens if the name conflicts and it starts assigning indexes with website name in project directory, i mean the .sln file.
or if somehow a different port no is used, then it does the same thing.
as said by yourself , its not a problem that is to be bothered...